# How to stop VSCode indenting when pushing existing code to a new line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, indentation

[image]

I have some code written, every time I press Enter to push it lower, it keeps indenting it.
Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indent is caused by the `onEnterRules` of the `full`/`advanced` setting of the `Editor: Auto Indent` preference:

[image: settings screenshot]

To avoid the problem, you could change the setting to `keep` or `none`, but be aware it changes your preference globally (for any file type where indenting would apply).

*It looks like there might be a [way to configure the `onEnterRules` per language](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11514), but I'm not entirely sure how to do that yet. Editing the [language specific setting in JSON](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) with the following config did **not** work for me:*

```
{
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.autoIndent": "keep"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for taking the time, @tony19!